# Python: Trying to create bar plot from data in multi-index pivot table

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, seaborn

I've seen some answers that are tangentially related to my question but they're sufficiently different that I'm still not sure how to go about this. I have a pivot table in Python organized as follows:

[image]

and I would like to create a bar plot where on the x-axis I have 6 sections for each of the 6 departments (A,B,C, etc.) and then for each I have two bar plots that show the value in the "Perc Admitted" column for Males and Females, with them colored differently for clarity. I've been trying to use Seaborn's barplot for this, but cannot seem to get it to come together, i.e. trying for example

```
sns.barplot(data = admit_data, x = 'Dept', y = 'Perc Accepted', hue = 'Gender')
```

gets me an "ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Dept'" error. Still learning Python and not sure how to best do this...any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm also open to using matplotlib.pyplot or other library if that also provides for an elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: `admit_data.reset_index()`

Comment: Great...thank you. Making that change indeed worked. For completeness/curiosity, is there a way to make this work without having to change the data structure and thereby still maintain the multi-index pivot table?